# Use GPU NVIDIA T600 on ubuntu 22.04 to train neural networks on tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu, gpu

I have a GPU NVIDIA T600 in my computer and I would like to use it to train neural networks on tensorflow, but tensorflow doesn't detect my GPU.

So I am working on Ubuntu 22.04 and I have installed the driver nvidia-driver-470. Everythong has been installed correctly and when I use the command nvidia-smi, I get the following output :

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 470.223.02   Driver Version: 470.223.02   CUDA Version: 11.4     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA T600 Lap...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   49C    P0     7W /  N/A |      4MiB /  3914MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      6045      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Then I have installed tensorflow with conda according to the procedure given in https://gretel.ai/blog/install-tensorflow-with-cuda-cdnn-and-gpu-support-in-4-easy-steps

Now I check the number of GPU available on my computer using the following command :

```
python3 -c "import os; os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'; import tensorflow as tf; print('Num GPUs Available: ', len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))"
```

The output is :

```
Num GPUs Available:  0
```

How can I do so that tensorflow recognizes my GPU?

Comment: what is tf version? did you try:
`pip install tensorflow-gpu`

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu

Comment: Yep, tried that and tried different versions. I got the same thing.